# Functions with dependencies passed as parameters

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I'm batch generating XML files which can import to the IDE of an industrial touchscreen.

Each XML file represents a screen, and most screens require the same functions and the process for dealing with them is the same, with the exception of the fact that each screen type has a unique configuration function.

I'm using a `ScreenType` class to hold attributes specific to a screen type, so I decided to write a unique configuration for each type, and pass it as a parameter to the `__init__()` of this class. This way, when I pass around my `ScreenType` as it is needed, it's configuration function will stay bundled and can be used whenever needed.

But I'm not sure what will happen if my configuration function itself has a dependency. For example:

```
def configure_inputdiag(a, b, c):
    numerical_formatting = get_numerics(a)
    # ...
    return configured_object
```

Then, when it comes time to create an instance of a `ScreenType`

```
myscreentype = ScreenType(foo, man, shoe, configure_inputdiag)
```

`get_numerics` is a module scoped function, but `myscreentype` could (and does) get passed within other modules.

Does this create a problem with dependencies? I'd try to test it myself, but it seems like I don't have a fundamental understanding behind what's going on when I pass a function as a parameter. I don't want to draw incorrect conclusions about what's happening.

What I've tried: Googling, Search SO, and I didn't find anything specifically for Python.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem.

The function `configure_inputdiag` will always refer to `get_numerics` in the context where it was defined. So, even if you call `configure_inputdiag` from some other module which knows nothing about `get_numerics`, it will work fine.

Passing a function as a parameter produces a reference to that function. Through that reference, you can call the function as if you had called it by name, without actually knowing the name (or the module from which it came). The reference is valid for the lifetime of the program, and will always refer to the same function. If you store the function reference, it basically becomes a different name for the same function.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do works in a very natural form in Python -

In the exampe above, you don't  need to have the "get_numerics"  function imported in the namespace (module) where the "configure_inputdiag" is - you just pass it as a normal parameter (say, call it "function")  and you are going like in this example:

Module A:

```
def get_numerics(parm):
    ...

input diag = module_B.configure_inputdiag(get_numerics, a)
```

Module B:

```
def configure_inputdiag(function, parm):
     result = function(parm)
```

Oh - I saw your doubt iwas the other waya round - anyway, there is no problem - in Python, functions are first class objects- jsut like ints and strings, and they can be passed around as parametrs to other functions in other modules as you wish.  I think the example above clarifies that.

Answer (score 2):

`get_numerics` is resolved in the scope of the function body, so it does not also need to be in the scope of the caller.